# Disabling/re-enabling form elements with vanilla js - Not working properly

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm using vanilla JS to try and disable/re-enable form elements depending on the value of one of the form elements selected.

```
        function editableFormElements() {
            let formElements = document.getElementById('NewCaseForm').elements;
            let assignedTo = document.getElementById('assignedTo');
            if(assignedTo.value == "pending")
            {
                for(x = 0; x < formElements.length; x++){
                    formElements[x].disabled = true;
                }
            }
            else{
                for(x = 0; x < formElements.length; x++){
                    formElements[x].disabled = false;
                }
            }
            assignedTo.disabled = false;
        }

        document.getElementById('assignedTo').addEventListener('change', editableFormElements);
```

I always want the 'assignedTo' element to be enabled, so I'm setting disabled to false again at the end of the function. The problem is, this doesn't seem to work. That form element remains disabled. What am I missing here?

Comment: There is a typo, there is a space after the period in `document. getElementById('assignedTo')` I don't know if that is in your code or not.

Comment: I corrected that in the code here (and my code, thanks for that!), but that didn't fix my issue.

Comment: can you provide a mini-repro of the bug ? I see nothng special on your code I try some simple code but I should works fine,

Comment: On a side note you can get rid of your if/else and just have ONE for loop and use this for setting the disabled: `formElements[x].disabled = (assignedTo.value == "pending");`

Comment: @KevinALBRECHT do you want the form?

Comment: @JesseEarley I think something outside this sample of code may do a side effect, have you tried the code you provided on a codepen or anything ? Thas should work.
Is nothing else dealing with the assignedTo element ? Or is you put a breakpoint before and after your last "assignedTo.disabled = false;" is the variable "assignedTo" still assigned ? is the property "disabled"  equal to false still ( but your view seems disabled  ) ?